# Unable to connect to my account [SOLVED]

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts, login

I am currently unable to access my MSE account (I’m user number 15381).
For years I used to connect from Yahoo without problems.
When I do that now I find myself connected as an entirely new, empty account.
I found that I can use the "account recovery page", but it still creates a brand new account, even though it recognizes my email as an already registered one.

Another strange thing : when in math mode, I see an empty account with 0 rep. When in meta mode I see my normal account with my current rep,22056.

How can I fix this ?

Update 09/11/2014 : Yesterday I could already access my old account, and today the two accounts are merged. Thanks to all those who helped me on this.

Comment: Have you fixed it? (Because it looks fixed.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Could you please say why it looks fixed to you ? Now at 21:30, it’s the same as before : in meta mode I have my old account, but in math mode I only have a new, empty account.

Comment: This account looks like your original account, the link from this account to the main page shows the original account...

Comment: @AsafKaragila To check, I just posted a question  at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920822/field-made-of-realimaginary-parts-of-members-of-another-field and it appears as a question of a totally new account.

Comment: Yeah, okay, that is a new account.

Comment: @AsafKaragila though this may not be visible to you, that new account's email is the same as my original account, which should be impossible in theory. So this looks definitely like a bug.

Comment: Can you connect to your meta account and click on the "main user" link? That should get you to your main account.  Then you can attempt to merge the accounts.

Comment: @robjohn when I do what you say, I get to my new empty account, not the original. As far I know, it is not possible to merge accounts if (as in my case) one does not have access to both accounts ?

Comment: For whatever it is worth, when I go to Math, Users, and type in Ewan, there are two of you, side by side. The first is your usual account, the other has a single question asked. I do not know how to solve the problem you have, except to suggest that if your browser allow it, you clear the cache of "recent" material.

Comment: You should [contact the SE team](http://math.stackexchange.com/contact) about this (using the "other" option, I think). Explain your situation, giving the user IDs for both accounts (this would be the numbers in the address of the profile: `http://math.stackexchange.com/users/<UserId>/<Display-Name>`). I will say that even though the email addresses are the same between the two accounts, the OpenID ("my logins") information is different. This might be what is causing your problems.

Comment: @ArthurFischer I did that this morning (except I used the "need to merge two accounts" option instead of "other"), but I got no answer yet. I’ll try several times anyway, and if the SE team stays unresponsive I'll eventually give up. I’ll record the developments as updates to this question

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: are saying that when you click on [the link boxed in red](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qrb5H.png), you get taken to the new account? That link takes me to your old main user.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: Keep in mind that the SE team is usually much less active on the weekends than they are during the week. Your message is in a queue of some sort, and someone will look at it, but I wouldn't be surprised if you have to wait at least until the work week begins. If I see a Community Manager in the _Teachers' Lounge_ I'll see if things can be sped up.

Comment: @robjohn when I click on "main user" as indicated in your screenshot, I indeed get taken to my old profile, but as an external user, as if I wasn’t me (for example, my email is not shown). And if I click on "ask question" from that old profile, I get redirected to my new account.

Comment: I've been told that the Comm Team should be looking into this today.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Thank you very much for your help.